# Joining two columns in an excel data frame without creating a new column

Tags: r

I am trying to join the information in two of my columns without creating a new column

Where SA is my dataframe and column 3 and 4 are the two columns that I am trying to join. This is the code that I have tried to use.

```
SA = unite(SA, c(SA[,3] , SA[,4]))
```

Answer (score 3):

`tidyr::unite()` has three required arguments:

- `data`
- `col`; name for the new column
- `...`; here you should insert the names of the columns you want to unite separated by commas

Since I don't have your `SA` dataset here is an example with made up data.

```r
library(tidyr)

SA <- tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  var1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace =  TRUE),
  var2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace =  TRUE),
  var3 = sample(1:10, 10, replace =  TRUE)
)

unite(SA, "new_col", var2, var3)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       id  var1 new_col
#>    <int> <int> <chr>  
#>  1     1     8 1_5    
#>  2     2     7 7_8    
#>  3     3     8 5_7    
#>  4     4     6 1_3    
#>  5     5     6 8_2    
#>  6     6     4 8_4    
#>  7     7     2 2_10   
#>  8     8     2 10_10  
#>  9     9     8 5_3    
#> 10    10     5 2_5
```

You can also use column indeces like so:

```r
unite(SA, "new_col", 3, 4)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>       id  var1 new_col
#>    <int> <int> <chr>  
#>  1     1     8 1_5    
#>  2     2     7 7_8    
#>  3     3     8 5_7    
#>  4     4     6 1_3    
#>  5     5     6 8_2    
#>  6     6     4 8_4    
#>  7     7     2 2_10   
#>  8     8     2 10_10  
#>  9     9     8 5_3    
#> 10    10     5 2_5
```